Maxwell's demon paradox and a Szilard engine
I’m now studying quantum information physics and have a question about Maxwell's demon paradox.
I know an explanation using a Szilard engine but I omit  the detailed settings as they are well known.
As I understand it, resolving this paradox requires a process in which the demon forgets the information in the demon’s memory and recovers the original state in order to complete the heat engine cycle.
Now suppose the devil  uses a human as a memory in place of himself to run the heat engine cycle.
If we only consider the demon and the heat engine, it is a perpetual motion machine, but since the human have information, if we take that into account, we can say that the second law of thermodynamics is not violated.
However, if the human forgets the information, how should we interpret this situation taking into account the second law of thermodynamics?
Does this mean that when the information is forgotten it turns into a different kind of energy?
And a more devilish question: if the devil wants to perfect a perpetual motion machine and somehow kills the human without using energy, where would the information go?
Does this mean that without the exchange of energy, people cannot die?
This may be a trivial question but I would like an answer.

"Does this mean that without the exchange of energy, people cannot die?" - "information" does not mean "a human knowing about it", it's a property of certain systems/interactions that determines how many bits/nats/whatevers you need to describe the system. It's a mathematical/physical thing, not a psychological thing. Not a full answer but hope that helps clear up the misunderstanding.

@ controlgroup
The reason I used a human as an analogy is just because I wanted to make it a bit philosophical.
At first, I was thinking of storing the information in classical bits or quantum bits, and then losing that information due to errors.
Errors occur when the information leaks out due to interactions with the external environment, so in the end, it's an exchange of energy.
I am wondering if there is a memory that can lose information without any external influence.

I mean theoretically sure you can have a system that behaves arbitrarily so long as it doesn’t directly violate physical laws (black holes seem to lose information that falls into them without external influence, for example). I would advise against bringing consciousness into physical questions, only for the post’s sake, since that might not count as “physics” and might make it off-topic.
